# Set background image using css

Tags: html, css

Here i upload the picture, i want to put my image to the left side of Food and Travel text[image]

```css
.block-title h3 {
  color: #151515;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.4;
  letter-spacing: -0.9px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <p>
    <center><img src="#">
      <div class="block-title">
        <h3>Food & Travel</h3>
      </div>
    </center>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use pseudo element `:before`

Comment: Well then float it, or make the div inline-block, or something like that … IMHO this is stuff you should not be asking here in the first place, but rather go through some tutorials that explain such _basics_ …

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a codepen or a jsfiddle with your implementation. WIll help you get a better answer suited to your needs.

Comment: <center> can not be used anymore https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add that line of **CSS**

```css
div.block-title { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <p>
    <center><img src="#">
      <div class="block-title">
        <h3>Food & Travel</h3>
      </div>
    </center>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your HTML a little bit:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="block-title">
        <img class="image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/45/45260.png">
        <h3 class="title">Food & Travel</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some observations about your HTML:

- Since the creation of CSS, it is considered a bad practice to use styling elements inside HTML, like *center*. HTML should hold only content and CSS styles. *center* in HTML can be, in most cases, easily replaced by *text-align: center* in CSS;
- Avoid giving styles to a tag (as you did with H3). It is always better to give a class for each individual element you want to style. For example, you can give a class to your image and to your header, as I did on the example above.

**Float**, as mentioned by some users here, is barely a good option. I would not recommend it.
I'd go for using **Flexbox** on the container (*block-title*). It is the better option and the most accurate.

Your container would be something like

```
.block-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

... and the magic is done!

Here is an example using **flexbox**:
https://codepen.io/annabranco/pen/mzEXGv

Another option if you are not comfortable with using Flebox yet, it's to give the H3 a **display: inline**. By default, all header force a line break (they have display: block). If you change it to *display: inline* you force the other elements to be displayed in the same line as your header.
In this case you would need to play around with **vertical-align** to find the exact spot where your text would be centered to the image.

```
.title {
    display: inline;
(..)
}

.image {
  vertical-align: -25px; //negative values go up and positive down.
}
```

Here is an another example, using **inline**:
https://codepen.io/annabranco/pen/yRJvQa